# how to search inside html string on fly through ExtJs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

In jquery we can do something like this :

```
$('a','<div><a></a></div>')
```

What is the equivalent in ExtJs ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot search html in extjs. You can only search ExtJs components using component query. For html search you can use native js.

Answer (score 0):

I tried lately something like this:

```
Ext.getDoc().dom.title = "My App Title";
```

Changes web page title.

So you can use Ext.getDoc().dom to access various parts of the page. 
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext-method-getDoc

I don't recommend accessing parts of ExtJS application like your example because stuff like that should be achieved using ExtJS practices, using MVC architecture, templates, component configurations.

Additional links: 
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.dom.Query